# My FireBase Database doesn't save information

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am working on my project and I need save information about my users. I chose Realtime Database, but it doesnt work. I have an exception:

> This email is already in use

through I insert new email. I use everything(google.json, SHA-1, SHA-256), but my signing up new users doesnt work correctly. My rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
    }
}
```

My class Person:

```
public String name, email;

    public User(){}

    public User(String name, String email){
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

My FireBaseAuth, FireBaseDataBase:

```
private  FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseDatabase usersDataBase;

///


 mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            User user = new User(username, email);

                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())
                                    .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Пользователь успешно добавлен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, SigningActivity.class));
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Произошла ошибка! Пожалуйста, попробуйте позже", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Are you sure the email doesn't already exist in the Firebase Console when you try to sign in again?

Comment: Yes, I have RegistrationActivity, there are three EditText for email, username and password. I did a lot of tests and every time I inserted random email, my email and userUID always are saved in Authentication->Users. But Realtime Database is always null

Comment: It's the call to `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` that is failing, so it makes sense that the database remains empty. Since the error message says that `This email is already in use`, that is really all we can say about it: you seem to be passing an email address that was already registered. If you are certain this is not the case, can you edit your question to show us more information that also helps us to see that the error message is wrong?